# Problema con menu de navegacion y los enlaces a las paginas

Tags: php, html

mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un archivo header que uso para hacer el include en todas las paginas, contiene el menu de navegacion, el navega entre sus distintas paginas pero primero debo pararme en inicio para poder navegar a otra pagina, si lo intento hacer entre paginas no funciona.

Entiendo que es por que el index esta a otro nivel en la estructura del proyecto. Solo quiero saber si hay manera de que los enlaces funcionen sin importar en que pagina este.

Este es mi header:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TIENDA</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="../../index.php">Inicio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Productos
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="php/crudProducto/producto.vista.php">Agregar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Entradas
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="php/crudEntrada/entrada.vista.php">Agregar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Cliente
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="php/crudCliente/cliente.vista.php">Agregar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Proveedor
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="php/crudProveedor/proveedor.vista.php">Agregar </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Ventas
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Agregar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

tienes varias opciones, te listo algunas:

1. Pones todas las vistas al mismo nivel
2. Creas un header diferente para los que no son index
3. Asumo que llamas al header en todas las páginas, entonces que en las páginas que llaman al header, se setee un path a concatenar en los links del nav así diferencias la raíz de la llamada
4. En vez de usar los paths "carpeta/archivo" usa "/carpeta/archivo" la diferencia de ese / extra es que tomas la ruta relativa al dominio, tú la estás usando relativa a la ruta del archivo que llama.
5. Setea todos tus links como rutas absolutas

Incluso puedo seguir dando alternativas, te recomendaría usar la 4 pero ahí tienes para escoger

Comment: Por que le han puesto -1 a mi respuesta si le di la solución?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder. Voy a intentar la opcion 4

Comment: Cualquier cosa me comentas